# Dockerfile targets different paths locally and it Gitlab

Tags: .net, docker, gitlab, copy, pipeline

Consider a dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils libgdiplus libc6-dev
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install openssl -y

#local env
COPY ["MyProject/MyProject/src/MainController/SslCertificates/", "/var/www/certs/"]

#gitlab env
COPY ["src/MainController/SslCertificates/", "/var/www/certs/"]
```

When I build and run dockerized application locally, line `#local env` assumes correct path for my files, but when I do the same in Gitlab build pipeline it fails to do so, failing to locate the certificates whereas line `#stage env` works fine in Gitlab build pipeline but not locally.

I'm no expert on pipelines so I thought about cheesing it like this:

```
COPY ["src/MainController/SslCertificates/", "/var/www/certs/"] || true && COPY ["MyProject/MyProject/src/MainController/SslCertificates/", "/var/www/certs/"]
```

but it fails with

```
1>failed to compute cache key: "/src/MainController/SslCertificates" not found: not found
```

How to deal with this issue either by making dockerfile assume correct path every time or ignoring errors from COPY directives?

docker build locally (from Visual Studio)

```
1>docker build -f "C:\Users\user\source\repos\MyProject\MyProject\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t potato:dev --target base  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=MyProject" "C:\Users\user\source\repos"
```

docker build gitlab (I have no idea)

```
docker buildx build --tag "${IMAGE_SHA}" --tag "${IMAGE_REF}" ${PUSH} .
```

Comment: What does your `docker build` command look like in each location, and what directory are you running the command from?

Comment: Added to the post. I'm not sure about the directory, locally I run the app using visual studio and in gitlab there is nothing indicating what the working directory is

Comment: On your local system, what does `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` output?

Comment: C:/Users/user/source/repos/MyProject/MyProject

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the context of your builds, which means the source for the copy commands is different. The argument to `docker build` (that isn't a flag) is the path to the build context, which is typically the root of the git repo or the path to the Dockerfile. I'd adjust the visual studio settings to match what you are doing in GitLab:

```
1>docker build --force-rm -t potato:dev --target base  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=MyProject" "C:\Users\user\source\repos\MyProject\MyProject"
```

Comment: How would I do this? Is it related to launchSettings.json?